# List of bytes in MVC model not generated in database by EF code first

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm developing MVC 4 application using EF code first and data anotations,
I have created a class which contains following properties:

public class Product

{

```
 [Key]
 [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public int ID {get; set; }

 [Required]
 [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Max 20 chars!")]
 [Display(Name = "name of product")]
 public string Name

 [Required]
 [Display(Name = "List of items included into product name")]
 public List<byte> ProductsNameCompositionList { get; set; }
```

}

ProductsNameCompositionList property actually reffers to enum:

public enum ProductNameCompositionElement : byte { CategoryName, PropertyNames, PropertyNamesWithValues }

when I start application all field of Product model are generated  in database automatically, 
except one - public List ProductsNameCompositionList not being created ....

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think EF knows how to map `List<byte>`. I would try just `byte[]`.

```
 [Required]
 [Display(Name = "List of items included into product name")]
 public byte[] ProductsNameCompositionList { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I have a field in database reffering to array of bytes!